# Cognos Schedule By Trigger - Unix

Tags: cognos

What would be the equivalent of trigger.bat in a UNIX Cognos installation? In a Windows installation, trigger based scheduling could be achieved managing the trigger.bat file. At least in the UNIX box I'm working on, there's no file named like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unix equivalent to trigger.bat is trigger.sh.